# Returning a string from VB.NET Function and storing it in Java Script

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, function, return

I am calling a VB.Net function in JavaScript and the function returns a string value which should be stored in the JavaScript variable.

The function is getting called but when I display the javascript variable in alert it shows the value as undefined. Is there any problem in returning values from VB.NET functions to JavaScript ?

Eg.,

//JavaScript function 
var a = ExampleMethod(3);

In the above example, the ExampleMethod(3) should return a string value.
Please help. I am not able to get any solution.

Update :
Please find my code here :

```
function fnDisplay(lid)
{
var test1 =CheckID(lid);
if(true)
{
alert(test1);
}
```

--

```
Public Function CheckID(ByVal idvalue As double) As String

//Some conditions here
return "Y"
End Function
```

I am calling the function through webservice method.When I debugged, it is going inside the method successfully. Only return value is a problem.

Comment: please add your complete code here

Comment: definitely you can do by using ajax method call. if you give some more information i can help you out. Post the code how you are calling vb method through javascript.

Comment: @Vandhana V  nobody can help you by looking into "fnndisplaytrue()" if you want the answer you need to post your part of code

Comment: Refer this site. By using webmethod and ajax call u can do. http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Check-UserName-Availability-in-ASP.Net-using-JQuery.aspx http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=109

Comment: Ajax can be a great tool in these situations. You can easily do such things  using ajax. Also i suggest use of jquery ajax since it is much simpler to achieve and debug. [Jquery ajax with vb.net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
function fnDisplay(lid)
{
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '../..../CheckID',
  data: { idvalue: lid},
  success:function(data) {
   if (data) {
        alert(data)
    }
   }
 });
}
```

try the function with ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>

Public Shared Function CheckID(ByVal idvalue As double) As String

   //Some conditions here

   Return returnValue

End Function


function fnDisplay(lid)
 {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Example.aspx/CheckID",
        data: '{idvalue: "' + lid + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response);
        }
    });
}
```